# stop tkinter mainloop disrupting matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

hi I'm a student and I'm working with ktinker for the first time. I am currently trying to create a program that follows this order:

1. open a map in matplotlib
2. a popup window is called for users to enter in information
3. when the user clicks on the map grid the coordinates and user
   info are stored in a dictionary
4. matplotlib generates a plot point on the location

The trouble is, when I call the popup window I have written in tkinter, calling the mainloop() function breaks the matplotlib window and it wont generate the plot points until the map window is closed.

getting rid of the mainloop fixes it but then means i cant get the data from the popup.
Anyone know how I can stop one from interfering with the other? i have to keep them in separate classes as Im meant to demonstrate modularity in my code.
here is the main code

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import popup1 as ap

__author__ = "k1221169"
__date__ = "$15-Nov-2015 11:29:21$"


markerList = []
xplots = []
yplots = []
desc = ''
title = ''
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))
img = mpimg.imread('overland map 1.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.ylim(ymax=1)
plt.xlim(xmin=1)


def mrkApnd(a,b):
    a.update(b)
    print a
    markerList.append(a)

def onclick(event):

    if spacecheck(event.xdata, event.ydata):
        #print markerList[0]['x']
        idx = np.abs(xplots - event.xdata).argmin()
        print xplots[idx]

        for i in markerList:
            if xplots[idx] == i['x'] :
                print i
                #c = i
                ap.useroutput(i)
    else:
        input1 = ap.userinput()
        input2 = {'x':event.xdata, 'y':event.ydata}
        input1['title'] = title
        input1['desc'] = desc
        mrkApnd(input1,input2)

        drawMarks()
        print input1

    return markerList
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

def drawMarks():
    plt.ion()
    for i in markerList:
        xplots.append(i['x'])
        yplots.append(i['y'])
        plt.plot(i['x'], i['y'], i['type'])





def spacecheck(x,y):
    a = bool
    if np.isclose(xplots, x, atol=50.0).any() and np.isclose(yplots, y, atol=50.00).any():
        a=True
        print 'yes'
        return a
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

and here is the popup code called from another file

```
from Tkinter import *

class popup1():
    def __init__(self):

        pass

def userinput():


    pop = Toplevel()


    pop.title("marker")
    pop.geometry("300x500+200+200")

    #string for title

    frame = Frame(pop)
    entry = Entry(frame)
    entry.pack(side = TOP)
    frame.pack( padx =20, pady =20)



    #radius button for visibility
    frame2 = Frame(pop)
    selection = StringVar()
    radio_1 = Radiobutton(frame2, text = 'Character', variable = selection, value = 'ob')
    radio_2 = Radiobutton(frame2, text = 'Item', variable = selection, value = 'or')
    radio_3 = Radiobutton(frame2, text='Event',  variable = selection, value = 'oy')

    radio_1.select()
    radio_1.pack(side = LEFT)
    radio_2.pack(side = LEFT)
    radio_3.pack(side = LEFT)
    frame2.pack(padx =30, pady =30)
    #radius button for marker type
    frame3 = Frame(pop)
    visible = bool
    check_1 = Checkbutton(frame3, text = 'GM Only', variable = visible, onvalue= True, offvalue= False)

    check_1.pack(side = LEFT)
    frame3.pack(padx =30, pady =30)
    #string for user input
    frame4 = Frame(pop)
    entry4 = Entry(frame4)
    entry4.pack(side = LEFT)
    frame4.pack( padx =20, pady =20)



    def infoPass():
        #info1 = {'title': entry.get(), 'type': selection.get(), 'vis': visible, 'Desc': entry4.get()}
        #info.update(info1)
        #print info

        pop.destroy()

    #buttons
    label = Label(pop, text="", height=0, width=100)
    label.pack()
    b = Button(pop, text="Cancel", width=20, command= pop.destroy )
    b.pack(side='bottom',padx=5,pady=5)
    b2 = Button(pop, text="Save", width=20, command= infoPass  )
    b2.pack(side='bottom',padx=5,pady=5)
    info = {'title': entry.get(), 'type': selection.get(), 'vis': visible, 'desc': entry4.get()}
    pop.mainloop()
    return info
```

Answer (score 0):

If i underdstood your question right, then try to add your own loop.

1. Remove pop.mainloop()
2. Make the code be a class for a cleaner code

```
    class userinput:
        def __init__(self):
            #open your window here and style it etc. and:
            self.data_sent = False
        def infopass(self):
            self.data_sent = True
            #your infopass code here and
```

3. Create your own loop at the end of **init**:

```
        def __init__(self):
            #...
            while self.data_sent == False:
                root.update()

    while data_sent == False:
        pop.update()
```

4. Call your popup by

   mypopup = userinput()

Good luck ;)